# Call function of a dynamically loaded instance of a es6 class

Tags: webpack, es6-modules, dynamic-import

I'm trying  to import "SampleModuleController" class dynamiclly using webpack and call its member function as follows.

sampleModule.js

```
  class SampleModuleController{
    
        getSampleModuleSheet()
        {
            console.log("getSampleModuleSheet");
        }
    
    }
    export let sampleModuleController = new SampleModuleController();
```

in a another class file...

```
async clicked(){
    const getView = await import('../../controllers/sampleModule');
    console.log("getView--",getView);
    getView.getSampleModuleSheet();
}
```

but it gives me following logs and errors

[image]

Comment: check if `async clicked(){
    const {sammpleModuleController} = await import('../../controllers/sampleModule');
    console.log("getView--",getView);
    sampleModuleController.getSampleModuleSheet();
}`

Comment: @me.nkr please give it as a answer .i will mark it as the correct one

Comment: Do not use a `class` if you want to create a singleton. Just write `export function getSampleModuleSheet() { … }` and your code would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    async clicked() {
      const {sammpleModuleController: getView} = await import ('../../controllers/sampleModule');
      console.log("getView--", getView);
      getView.getSampleModuleSheet();
    }
```